# Find and Replace with Visual Studio Code to replace cell alignment with a class

Tags: visual-studio-code

Since the [align attribute is considered obselete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div#Attributes) I am cleaning up code to remove it and replace with a CSS class.  I'm trying to determine if there is a way to do this using find and replace (or something else) in VS Code.

As an example, I might have some html that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" class="someclass" id="mainTitleCell" title="Title1">Title1</td>
        <td align="center" title="Title2">Title2</td>
        <td class="someclass" align="right" title="Title3">Title3</td> <!-- attributes are not always in the same order -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Title</td>
        <td align="center">Title</td>
        <td align="right">Title</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

which I would like to change to

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="left someclass" id="mainTitleCell" title="Title1">Title1</td>
        <td class="center" title="Title2">Title2</td>
        <td class="right someclass" title="Title3">Title3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="left">Content</td>
        <td class="center">Content</td>
        <td class="right">Content</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Basically removing the `align` attribute and either adding a class attribute with a specific value OR adding a specific value to an existing class attribute.  Is there a way to do this with the Edit...Replace option in VS Code?  I know I can find based on a regex but not sure how I would go about the replace since this becomes

1. Find the align tag
2. Remove it
3. Find a class attribute in the `<td>` or `<th>` tag and add the appropriate class
4. If there is no class attribute, add one with the appropriate class.

Obviously step #1 & 2 are easy, it's #3 & 4 that I'm not sure of.  I'd be totally happy with having to run 3 separate find and replace commands (one for left, center and right).

Do I have any options here (I am open to extensions)?

**UPDATE**:

> @Mark had the right answer and I was able to chain together several find and replace commands using the [Replace Rules extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bhughes339.replacerules#review-details).  With that I can open a file, run a single keystroke to find and replace everything and clean up the extra spaces in the class attribute.

Comment: Did you try regex? Here's what I'd do first. Copy a block of HTML to notepad++ then practice writing regex and replacements.  It will allow you to undo results each time you miss something. Then when ready use in vs code search window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Find: `align="(.*?)"(.*?) class="(.*?)"|class="(.*?)"(.*?) align="(.*?)"|align="(.*?)"`

Replace: `class="$7$1$6 $3$4"$2$5`

See [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/tAtNAO/2).

I'm a little surprised this works as well as it does (I included a couple of other test cases you didn't).  The only issue (thus far...) is that it can result in one stray space, as in:

`<td class="left ">Title</td>`   // only happens when there is no `class` attribute

as you can see in the demo page.  You could then search for  `"` and replace with just `"`.  It could be handled by a conditional replacement but vscode find/replace doesn't allow those.

To some degree attributes will be re-ordered so that the `class` attribute is first, but not always - you didn't mention that as a concern - any attribute that occurs before either the first `class` or `align` attribute will not be moved.  Otherwise, attributes like `id` or `title` if they are between `class`<->`attribute` (in any order) will be put last.

Comment: Works perfect.  I can now easily chain this with a few other find and replace commands to eliminate the class="left " situation.